# Specifying the MOXy runtime for multiple Java packages

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Is there a way to specify MOXy as my JAXB implementation, for domain classes spread across multiple Java packages, other than putting [`jaxb.properties`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/SpecifyRuntime) into every single package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the JAXB provider you need to put a jaxb.properties in one of the packages for your domain objects, that is **passed in** to bootstrap the JAXBContext.  For example if your JAXBContext will be based on the following 2 classes:

- example.foo.Foo
- example.bar.Bar

**example.foo.Foo**

```
package example.foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

import example.bar.Bar;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

}
```

**example.bar.Bar**

```
package example.bar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

import example.foo.Foo;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {

    private Foo foo;

}
```

**example/foo/jaxb.properties**

To specify that the MOXy implementation of JAXB should be used we will put a jaxb.properties file with the following entry in the same package as the Foo class.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

Since the Foo and Bar classes reference each other, ultimately the JAXBContext will contain metadata about both of them, but based on how we create the JAXBContext the provider can be different.

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import example.foo.Foo;
import example.bar.Bar;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Bar.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, Bar.class).getClass());
    }

}
```

Running the above code will produce:

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
```

Comment: Adding `jaxb.properties` to only one package appears to only affect the classes in that particular package.

Comment: How are you bootstrapping the JAXBContext?

Comment: My tests to verify this simply printed out the result of `JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).getClass().getName()` for 2 different values of `Foo.class`; one in a package containing `jaxb.properties` and one in a package not containing the file. Anyway, this issue is less of a blocker than my other question I know you're working on right now. I'm going to table this for now until the bigger issue is resolved. Thanks for your help, btw!

Comment: @Matt Ball - No problem, I have updated my answer with an example demonstrating how a JAXB provider is chosen based on the jaxb.properties file.

Comment: Ok, this is good enough for me. I'm not sure how Jersey bootstraps its JAXBContext but I was able to remove `jaxb.properties` from all but 2 out of 7 (and rising) packages. Thank you for the help.