# Check my JAXB implementation

Tags: xml, jaxb, moxy

I am trying to use Eclipselink's MOXy.  I put jaxb.properties file in the same directory as my annotated classes and it contains the entry:

javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

Is there anyway I can be sure this implementation is being used at runtime?
For example, I can check my StAX implementation is Woodstox by checking:

inputFactory.getClass().getName() is equal com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory

Is there anything similar I can do to check my JAXB implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5863343/139010):

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import example.foo.Foo;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).getClass());
        // If MOXy is used, this will print:
        // class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah some more info here as well: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Yup, Blaise is an awesome source of information for all things JAXB. I didn't notice that he made a blog post about it!

Comment: Yeah it's pretty good.  Editors you can delete this thread if you want.