# How do you create a POJO containing a list that the container has attributes?

Tags: list, attributes, jaxb, pojo

How do you create a POJO containing a list that the container has attributes?

Typically when creating a POJO of a list you do it the following way:

To represent the following XML structure:

```xml
<folder>
    <messages>
        <message>
            <subject>XXXX</subject>
            ...
        </message>
        <message>
            <subject>XXXX</subject>
            ...
        </message>
    </messages>
</folder>
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "folder")
public class Folder {
    @XmlElement
    private List<Message> messages;
    ...
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "message")
public class Message {
    @XmlElement
    private String subject;
    ...
}
```

But how do you represent a POJO when there are attributes at the messages tag? i.e.

```xml
<folder>
    <messages total="45" start="3">
        <message>
            <subject>XXXX</subject>
            ...
        </message>
        <message>
            <subject>XXXX</subject>
            ...
        </message>
    </messages>
</folder>
```

Do you create a POJO specifically for messages and then map a List of Message with an annotation of `@XmlValue` or something along those lines?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Which JAXB provider are you using?

Comment: I'm using javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext. I'm trying to figure out if there is an external dependency that maven is adding but I can't seem to find a reference to jaxb. I'll try to figure it out and get back to you in a moment.

Comment: There are pretty much only 2 choices: [JAXB RI](http://jaxb.java.net/) and [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). Here's how to figure out which one you're using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626952/check-my-jaxb-implementation/8626974#8626974

Comment: Ok, give me one second to set it up and I'll let you know in a couple minutes.

Comment: Came back with:
 class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

So I believe that means JAXB RI

Comment: It seems as if this is possibly my solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311374/binding-xml-using-pojo-and-jaxb-annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach could be used with any JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.

**Messages**

Using just the standard JAXB (JSR-222) APIs you will need to introduce a `Messages` class to your model.

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Messages {

    @XmlElement(name="message")
    private List<Message> messages;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int start;

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getTotal() {
        if(null == messages) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return messages.size();
        }
    }

}
```

**Folder**

Then you will need to modify your `Folder` class to reference the new `Messages` class.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Folder {

    private Messages messages;
}
```

**Message**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message {

    private String subject;

}
```

Comment: This was the correct answer that I got working. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group

If you use MOXy as your JAXB provider then you could leverage the `@XmlPath` extension and do the following.

**Folder**

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Folder {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="message")
    private List<Message> messages;

    @XmlPath("messages/@start")
    private int start;

    @XmlPath("messages/@total")
    public int getTotal() {
        if(null == messages) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return messages.size();
        }
    }
}
```

**Message**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message {

    private String subject;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Folder.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14372107/input.xml");
        Folder folder = (Folder) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(folder, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<folder>
   <messages start="1" total="2">
      <message>
         <subject>XXXX</subject>
      </message>
      <message>
         <subject>YYYY</subject>
      </message>
   </messages>
</folder>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html